# Dotnet Core - Hangfire - Dependency Injection and HTTPClient

Tags: c#, .net-core, hangfire

I'm looking to get an understanding of how the Hangfire library handles DI in dotnet core, as that might be the cause of some issues we are observing.

We are using Hangfire in our dotnet core application. The background jobs that we schedule with Hangfire using the HTTPClient to make requests. We initialise the client in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddHttpClient("http-client", client =>
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://www.api.com/api/");
            });
```

Now, we use DI to inject the IHttpClientFactory httpClientFactory into an object from which we then schedule a background job that will use the client to make a connection to an API.

Using the HTTPClientFactory, we thought we would not run in socket starvation issues, but it appears we are indeed.

When we looked into Hangfire and set breakpoints inside the jobs, it looks like a new HTTPClient is being generated for every new jobs... it's almost like HangFire recreates a new DI scope for every job, so Singletons actually are recreated for all new jobs... which is not my definition of a Singleton.

Are we missing something major in the way Hangfire uses dotnet core default DI?